# Error while updating npm version

Tags: node.js, git, npm

When I try:

```
npm i -g npm to udpate
```

I get following error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/local/bin/git clone -q git://github.com/jonschlinkert/resolve-file.git /Users/my/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-d70e67af
npm ERR! /Users/my/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-d70e67af/.**git: Permission denied**
```

This indicates that Git is not authorized enough. I try to use sudo to execute, and the execution result is the same.

Comment: Please be specific about the question and issue in the title of the question. Hope my answer below will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `sudo` command with npm command. It needs permissions.

Try this command:

```
sudo npm i -g npm@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, npm with `sudo` cause npm is global mode

```
sudo npm i -g npm
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is wrong. You can refer [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-updates) or This also can use.

sudo npm i -g npm@latest